# После переименования скрипта в Visual Studio в инспекторе Unity появляется ошибка

Tags: unity3d

Переименовал скрипт в `Visual Studio`, назывался `MobSpawner` переименовал на `EnemySpawner`, на объекте где был скрипт появилась такая ошибка `"The associated script can not be loaded. Please fix any compile errors and assign a valid script"`

И скрипт перестает работать, незнаю что делать а переименовать надо.

[image: Link]

---

> Если Вы столкнулись с такой проблемой, то я ответом на этот вопрос
> помогу решить данную задачу

---

Answer (score 0):

Помимо этого скрипт может отображаться как и `Missing (Mono Script)`, что тоже быть связан с данной проблем

Это происходит потому что у каждого объекта есть свои специальные id привязанные ко всем юнити ассетам которые хранятся в мета файлах каждого объекта, и во время переименования через `Visual Studio` (не знаю есть ли такие же проблемы и у `Rider`) к сожалению `Unity` переписывает мета файлы, и у объекта меняется ID от этого и теряются ссылки у объектов к которым они были добавлены.

У меня есть решение которое поможет переименовывать объекты не теряя ссылок

Надо найти скрипт для начала, я всегда ищу через `Unity`, находите в `Project` окне ваш скрипт, правой кнопкой мыши и `Show in Explorer`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее находите там свой скрипт с его мета файлом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переименовываете его там же вместе с мета файлом (только название оставляя разрешение .cs.meta)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как мы переименовали только файл, необходимо теперь переименовать скрипт, заходим в наш скрипт, и переименовываем в соответствии с названием файла (`EnemySpawner`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> ВАЖНЫЙ МОМЕНТ: IDE в этот момент видит изменение в название, и выделяет его квадратом из пунктиров, после введения название следует нажать `Alt+Enter` во время выделения такого квадрата и получите возможность применить изменения во всем проекте выбрав `Переименовать "MobSpawner" в "EnemySpawner"`, чтобы все обьекты которые ссылались на данный класс тоже получили новое название и не потеряли ссылки
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сохраняем изменение, открываем `Unity` и видим успешное изменение с сохранением всех ссылок. Потому что мы изменили название обьекта не теряя его мета файлы